# Changing 'string' to 'int' to carry out addition of two numbers

Tags: java, addition

I am creating a java web service that has an addition function. I am suppose to get the sum of 1 + 1 as '2' instead i get '11'. What do i do to fix this error?

Here are my codes:

**Addition.java**

```
public class Addition {

private String firstNumber, secondNumber, sum;

public Addition(String firstNumber, String secondNumber, String sum) {
    this.firstNumber = firstNumber;
    this.secondNumber = secondNumber;
    this.sum = firstNumber+secondNumber;
}

public String getFirstNumber() {
    return firstNumber;
}

public void setFirstNumber(String first) {
    this.firstNumber = first;
}

public String getSecondNumber() {
    return secondNumber;
}

public void setSecondNumber(String second) {
    this.secondNumber = second;
}

public String getSum() {
    return sum;
}

public void setSum(String sum) {
    this.sum = sum;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Addition [firstNumber=" + firstNumber + ", secondNumber=" + 
    secondNumber + ", sum=" + sum + "]";
}
```

**AdditionController.java**

```
@RestController
public class AdditionController {

private static final String template = " %s";

@RequestMapping("/addition")
@ResponseBody 
public Addition addition (
        @RequestParam(value="firstNumber", defaultValue="1") String firstNumber,
        @RequestParam(value="secondNumber", defaultValue="1") String secondNumber,
        @RequestParam(value="sum", defaultValue="2") String sum){
         return new Addition(
            String.format(template, firstNumber),
            String.format(template, secondNumber),
            String.format(template, sum));
   }  
}
```

I am not able to change the 'string' to 'int' as i face more errors if i try to do that. Someone please help me. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: If you want to do math, not everything can be a `String`. There's no reason that I can see why your controller and service shouldn't just accept numeric data types straight off the bat.

Comment: you need to convert `String` to `int`

Comment: *I am not able to change the 'string' to 'int' as i face more errors if i try to do that.* What errors?

Comment: Why do not you declare your `@RequestParam`s as `int` (or `Integer`)?

Comment: `private static final String template = " %s";` I have that line of code which displays `{"firstNumber":" 1","secondNumber":" 1","sum":" 1 1"}` when i run the web service. If i change anything in my addition.java class, i do not get the end data that i should

Comment: If i change anything to int,  get directed to a white page and i don't get `{"firstNumber":" 1","secondNumber":" 1","sum":" 1 1"}` this line out. Too mixed up with the `string` and `int`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have already pointed out in the comments, if you want to sum `int` values you must *parse* the `String`(s) to `int`(s) somewhere; you could do so in the constructor. I have provided an, almost, drop in replacement below - however, I see no point in passing `sum` into the class (or in providing a direct mutator for the sum); instead I would recalculate on update for the first or second number. Like,

```
public class Addition {
    private int firstNumber, secondNumber, sum;

    public Addition(String firstNumber, String secondNumber) {
        this.firstNumber = Integer.parseInt(firstNumber.trim());
        this.secondNumber = Integer.parseInt(secondNumber.trim());
        updateSum();
    }

    public int getFirstNumber() {
        return firstNumber;
    }

    public void setFirstNumber(int firstNumber) {
        this.firstNumber = firstNumber;
        updateSum();
    }

    public int getSecondNumber() {
        return secondNumber;
    }

    public void setSecondNumber(int secondNumber) {
        this.secondNumber = secondNumber;
        updateSum();
    }

    public int getSum() {
        return sum;
    }

    private void updateSum() {
        this.sum = this.firstNumber + this.secondNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Addition [firstNumber=%d, secondNumber=%d, sum=%d%n", //
                firstNumber, secondNumber, sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you so much. Do i have to make any changes to the AdditionController.java class?

Comment: `return new Addition(
            String.format(template, firstNumber),
            String.format(template, secondNumber));`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change any definition then just for work-around try changing only this line:

```
this.sum = firstNumber+secondNumber;
```

to

`this.sum = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(firstNumber.trim())+Integer.parseInt(secondNumber.trim()));`

Don't forget to handle exception.

***N.B.:*** This is not the right way. Just work around.

Comment: I get the error: `incompatible types: int cannot be converted to String`

Comment: Do i have to change more stuff?